# Cisco ASA intermittently fails to see traffic

Tags: networking, cisco, cisco-asa

```
users 
 |
Mikrotik -- Internet
 | 
ASA
 |
ServerA and ServerB
```

I'm trying to troubleshoot a problem with a new Cisco ASA 5505.  The network design is as above - the Microtik is the existing router, ServerA and ServerB used to plug directly into it.

ServerA has IP 10.30.1.10, ServerB has IP 10.30.1.11
The ASA is configured with no NAT, a "allow anything" firewall, and uses the microtik as its default gateway.  In effect, it is currently a simple IP router; the firewall and VPN stuff will all come later once the basics are working.

Th problem is access to ServerA and ServerB is erratic - sometimes it will work, sometimes it will fail.  It can fail for either one of the servers only, or both.

When it is working:
The Mikrotik logs show ping packets being sent out over the proper interface
The ASA logs show the incoming connections.

When it is failing:
The Mikrotik logs show ping packets being sent out over the proper interface
The ASA logs show nothing reaching the ASA.

This can fail for one server only (e.g.: the Mikrotik is putting out packets to 10.30.1.10 and 10.30.1.11, but the ASA is only seeing packets arrive destined for  10.30.1.11)
It can fail for one source only (e.g.: ClientA on the users network can ping 10.30.1.11, but clientB cannot)
The problem can also be seen from the mikrotik router itself; sometimes it can ping ServerA and ServerB, sometimes it can only ping one of them

What could be causing this?  I can't think of any possible cause that is intermittent and could explain why the problem may occur for one destination server and not others.

edit:
[Link to ASA config](https://fuber.uberconsult.com/doug/clean_20090921_1330.txt)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was eventually traced to a problem in the Mikrotik router; when we upgraded the firmware it resolved this problem.

Answer (score 1):

I wonder if you need to put in identity NAT configs on the ASA:

```
nat (inside) 0 0 0
nat (dmz) 0 0 0
```

Also, check the ARP tables on the ASA (show arp) and the servers to make sure they have the correct IP->hw addresses.

And check the routing tables on every device as well.

Comment: no NAT, checking the ARP table is a good idea.

I've managed to determine that the problem only occurs if both servers are connected, so I'll repost a simplified version of the question with new information.